# need a function for determing the scale of a value

Tags: python, numpy

lets say i have some values: .008, .08, .8, 8, 80, 800.  I need a function where i can input these values and return .001, .01, .1, 1, 10, 100 etc...

example:

```
def func(v):
    a = do something using v.....
    return a

func(.009) = .001
func(.06)  = .01 
func(1234) = 1000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import math
>>> 10**math.floor(math.log10(.009))
0.001
>>> 10**math.floor(math.log10(.06)) 
0.01
>>> 10**math.floor(math.log10(1234))
1000.0
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
from math import log, floor
def func(v):
   a = floor(log(v, 10))
   return 10**a
```

Comment: you should use `math.log10`

Answer (score 0):

i wont write the function for you as this is probably something you should do yourself, but in terms of psuedocode, do something like this:

```
def func(v):
    new str;
    length = len(v) - 1
    if v[0] == '.':
        str = '.'
        for x in range (0, length):
            if x == length - 1:
                str = str + '1'
            else:
                str = str + '0'
    else:
        str = '1';
        for x in range (0, length):
            str = str + '0'
    return str.toInteger()
```

basically you find the length of the number and subtract it by one. the reason for this is because you know what is going to be the first character of your result. its either a decimal or a 1. we check the first element of the string (if its a number, convert it to string). if the first element is a decimal, the result will be a decimal and then you use the length of the number - 1 (aka length of number without the decimal) to figure out how many 0 and 1s to concatonate to the string. if the input is not a decimal number, then you just have the str = '1'. then add 0's to it according to its length - 1 (aka subtract the 0).

now im not sure if the situation will come up for you or not, but if your number is like 20.25, then its the same thing except if you the first character is a number and not a decimal, you need to check if the rest of the string is a decimal.

you will notice i say string a lot in my response because its easier if it was a string. if its a number, convert it to string because its easier to manipulate.